# Unable to Load 3D Object from External File with SceneKit on macOS

Tags: macos, 3d, scenekit

I would like to load a 3D object from an external file, with an extension like .obj, .dae or .abc, into a `SCNView` view and I want to do it programmatically, so the user decides which object is loaded. I'm doing it in this way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scnView: SCNView!
scnView.scene = SCNScene()
let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["obj", "dae", "abc"]

openPanel.begin { (result) in   
    if result == .OK, let docURL = openPanel.urls.first {
        let scene = try! SCNScene(url: docURL, options: nil)
        self.scnView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(scene.rootNode.clone())
    }
}
```

When I load a 3D object with a .obj extension, the `scene` object is correctly populated with the 3D model, but the only thing I can see is this message from the console:

```
 2017-12-17 21:27:39.734165+0100 DemoApp[15244:959862] Unable to projec to 2D plane
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find out what is causing the bizarre (misspelled) Xcode error in the console "Unable to projec to 2D plane". I have no noticeable symptoms, except perhaps slower loadtime, and a lot of spam in the console as the message "Unable to projec to 2D plane" repeats itself a hundred times.